# How to get the coordinate of element tag inside link function of angularJs directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs-directive

I am implementing tool tip through directive in AngularJS but not able to get the element coordinate.
When my tooltip will be visible i want to get the coordinate of that position and want to display it
according to the position.

```
'use strict';
var utility = angular.module("utility", []);

utility.directive("tooltip", function () {

    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'A';
    directive.transclude = true;

    directive.link = function ($scope, element, attributes) {
        element.html("This is the new content: ");
        element.bind('mouseenter', createDiv);
        element.bind('mouseleave', destroyDiv);


        function createDiv() {

            //need the coordinate of the pointer to display div on hover of attribute.

            var divTag = document.createElement("div");
            var toolTipHtml;
            divTag.id = "divToolTip";
            divTag.setAttribute("align", "center");
            //divTag.style.border = "1px solid #ccc";
            divTag.style.zIndex = "999";
            divTag.style.position = "absolute"
            divTag.style.width = "200px";
            divTag.style.height = "115px";
            toolTipHtml = "<div style=\" opacity:0.8; border-bottom:15px solid #000; border-left:10px solid transparent;border-right:10px solid transparent;width:0;height:0; \"></div>"
            toolTipHtml += "<div style = \"background-color:black; opacity:0.8;  border: 1px solid #F11; width:98%; height:95%; -webkit-border-radius:20px; position:relative;\">";
            toolTipHtml += "<div style=\" width:96%; height:10px; margin-top:15px;\"> <div style=\" float:left; width:90%; height:9px;\"></div> <div style=\" float:left; width:10%\">  <img src=\"./img/close.png\" alt=\"HTML Tutorial\"/> </div> </div>";
            toolTipHtml += "<div style=\"float:left; width:150px;\"/> " + $scope.toolTipData.message + "</div>";
            toolTipHtml += "</div>";

            divTag.innerHTML = toolTipHtml;

            element.append(divTag);
        }

        function destroyDiv() {
            var divTag = document.getElementById("divToolTip");
            divTag.remove();
        }
    }

    directive.scope = true;

    return directive;


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**angular.element** is a ***jQuery compatible API***.

If jQuery library is included in the page it actually uses jQuery but this is not a dependency.

Since the first argument of any event handler in jQuery is the event object, you need to pass that argument to your event handler function and then you can access coordinates.

```
function createDiv(event){

   var pageX = event.pageX,
       pageY = event.pageY;

       /* your existing code */
}
```

You can also use it to create and manipulate your new elements .

```
var divTag = angular.element('<div>');
divTag.css({zIndex:999, position:'absolute', width: 200, height: 115});
```

Reference : [**angular.element docs**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)